# Parsing yaml using jackson databind causes MismatchedInputException

Tags: java, jackson, yaml, fasterxml

The format of yaml I am trying to read is as follows

```
- name: storage
  scm: git
  src: git+https://bitbucket.org/cer/linux_storage_jenkins.git
  version: '5'
- name: linux_jenkins
  scm: git
  src: git+https://bitbucket.org/cer/linux_jenkins.git
  version: '8'
```

My model is simple

```
public class Requirementsyml {
    //setter and getter in place
    private List<Requirement> items;
}

public class Requirement {
    private String name;
    private String scm;
    private String src;
    private String version;
}
```

I am trying to read the yaml contents as follows:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
Requirementsyml req = mapper.readValue(yaml_file_content, Requirementsyml.class);
```

However I am getting the following exception
`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of Requirementsyml out of START_ARRAY token`

Since the model has a list I think the input should not be mismatched. 
I tried to provide yaml file as a java file object, instead of its content as string. The result remains the same. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yaml structure should be having `items` array/list

```
items:
- name: storage
  scm: git
  src: git+https://bitbucket.org/cer/linux_storage_jenkins.git
  version: '5'
- name: linux_jenkins
  scm: git
  src: git+https://bitbucket.org/cer/linux_jenkins.git
  version: '8'
```

or else you can read it as list of requirements with no change to yaml

```
@Test
void test() throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
    List<Requirement> requirements = mapper.readValue(new File("src/test/resources/requirements.yml"), new TypeReference<List<Requirement>>() {});
    assertEquals(2, requirements.size());
}
```

also make sure `Requirement` and other class has no args constructor, otherwise set appropriate flags on `ObjectMapper`